# Is assault against the first precept?

Tags: five-precepts, ethics

The first precept states

> I undertake the training rule to abstain from killing.

So does this mean that punching someone in the nose isn't actually against the first precept and the five precepts generally. It really feels like it should be.

Comment: Just to note this came out of a very interesting chat with  Sankha Kulathantille in one of the chat rooms so I just wanted to open this one up to the community generally.

Comment: Stiff thinking is a great obstacle on a path to awakening. Do we really need a written rule so we know that punching someone is bad? I won't punch a guy because it creates suffering, not because I'm afraid to break some rules.

Comment: @Rabbit I agree. There are a lot of questions on that site in the form of does XXXX break this or that precept. I think these are interesting but I'm not convinced about there ultimate use in Buddhist practice. I think there is a general question in there to ask - if I can phrase it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *Pāḷi* word for "killing living beings" is usually *pāṇātipātā*. It is composed by *pāṇa* + *atipātā*:

- *pāṇa*, in this context, is normally translated as "living being".
- *atipātā* is the useful word for answering the question. It can mean "killing, destroying, injuring or attacking".

Technically, it will depend on how one translates it. Either as killing\destroying or injuring\attacking. However, if one takes into account the entire Buddha's teaching it is evident, at least for me, that it means injuring\attacking, not only killing\destroying.

So I would say, yes, assault is against the first precept. However, one should always keep in mind that intention is key. One can injure a baby, for example, by extracting from his throat a swallowed toy. In such cases, I wouldn't consider it as against the first precept.

Answer (score 7):

The following five conditions must be satisfied to break the first precept.

1. The being must be alive.
2. There must be knowledge that it is a living being
3. There must be intention to cause its death
4. Action must be taken to cause its death
5. Death must result from such action

So punching someone in the nose does not break the 1st precept. But it weakens it. Since the question is if it's against(not if it breaks) the precept, the answer is yes.

Weakening here means the merits you acquire by keeping to first precept are reduced or weakened. Also, when it comes to the consequences of Kamma, Killing results in one having a short life span if born as a human again. Just injuring or torturing results in having bad health if born as a human again. killing usually involves inflicting pain or torturing as well. So it can result in bad health too.

Answer (score 4):

The precepts are usually expressed in purely negative terms, but they are intended to express much broader positive principles. In other words, keeping the precepts is just as much about keeping the spirit of the law as it is the letter. For example, in the case of the first precept, the Buddha gives this description:

> "And how is a monk consummate in virtue? Abandoning the taking of
>   life, he abstains from the taking of life. He dwells with his rod laid
>   down, his knife laid down, scrupulous, merciful, compassionate for the
>   welfare of all living beings. This is part of his virtue."

(Source: http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.02.0.than.html )

Assault is clearly against the positive principle in the first precept regardless of whether or not it fits within the strict wording of the precept. Hitting someone might not be classified as *pāṇātipātā* but it certainly is incompatible with having mercy and compassion.

Answer (score 2):

according to the first precept of the Buddhism, it break when a individual/animal killing another individual intentionally.
for break the first precept have to completes following stages

```
  1. there are living thing
  2. think to kill that individual/animal (living thing)
  3. get some action to kill 
  4. killing
```

NOTE that intention to killing is most important factor of this process. that mean if someone died and there is some connection to you about that, but if you had not any intention or though for kill him you not break the precept.
NOTE if some one harm or violation on other [not killing] (intentionally), that negative harmful behavior cause to damage the precept and accumulate negative karma.

Answer (score 1):

Not all harmful actions fall under the five precepts.  The Five Noble Precepts are the **minimum** conduct guidelines for a practicing Buddhist. This does not mean that violence that falls short of killing is therefore in accordance with the Buddha's teachings!

Fortunately, the Buddha's teachings are not affected by what people feel they should be.  :)